# Cast away nested Option in Kotlin arrow

Tags: kotlin, arrow-kt

I have a value with below type in my data class

```
Option<Option<List<Pair<String, Option<String>>>>>
```

How would I access the right-most `Option<Sring>`. I have tried with when expression like below

```
when(Option<Option<List<Pair<String, Option<String>>>>>) {
is Some -> when(Option<Option<List<Pair<String, Option<String>>>>>.t) {
           is Some -> when(Option<List<Pair<String, Option<String>>>>.t) {
......
```

but it's not looking good. Is there any other way to cast away those Options

Comment: Do you expect to get List<Option<String>> or List<String>?

Comment: @JakubZalas right part of pair "Option<String> " for the particular list index

Answer (score 2):

```kotlin
val t: Option<Option<List<Pair<String, Option<String>>>>> =
    Some(Some(listOf(
         Pair("a", Some("A")),
         Pair("b", Some("B")),
         Pair("c", None)
    )))

val l = t.flatten()
         .map { list ->
             list.map { pair -> pair.second }
         }
         .getOrElse { emptyList() }

val first = l.getOrElse(0) { None }
val second = l.getOrElse(1) { None }
val missing = l.getOrElse(7) { None }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
nested  // Option<Option<List<Pair<String, Option<String>>>>>
  .flatten() // Option<List<Pair<String, Option<String>>>>
  .map { it.map { it.second() } } // Option<List<Option<String>>>
  .sequence(Option.applicative()) // Option<Option<List<String>>>
  .flatten() // Option<List<String>>
```

`flatten` gets rid of nested options, and `sequence` goes from `List<Option<A>>` to `Option<List<A>>`.